# Jquery wont work on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, animation, button

http://projoh.altervista.org/

Works fine on firefox, chrome, but NOT on IE 11(Great.)

It seems like jQuery isn't loading, but .css and Stickup are working fine(Bottom of the page javascript works, everything from script.js wont work only on IE)?

Buttons should fade in plus things and such.

I've used the same type of fade in code etc, and it worked fine on IE before

Comment: F12 debug tools in IE. View console... "SCRIPT5: Access is denied". "pubchart, line 1 character 1"

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A lot. Run your webpage throught the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) - you have **54 Errors, 5 warning(s)**.

Comment: You're also missing a DOCTYPE at the top. Not probably what's breaking jQuery, but is worth noting.